# Why can't Traefik find a container on the same network?

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik

I have setup Docker Swarm with 3 nodes. They are all configured as part of the cluster. The master node is also a host for containers.

Each node has an NFS mount to NFS to store centralised data.

I have created an ElasticSearch cluster that is global, so it runs on all the nodes. This is configured to run in Docker Swarm using DNS Round Robin (`dnsrr`) in the cluser. As `dnsrr` does not allow ports to be exposed I have an Nginx proxy server that listens for requests on 19200 and then proxies them to the service `elasticsearch` on port 9200.

The Traefik, ElasticSearch Proxy and ElasticSearch nodes are all attached to the same overlay network called `elastic_cluster`. The network is `10.0.10.0/24`.

I have configured Traefik so that it has a named host and answers to `elasticsearch.homenetwork.local` (not real domain) on port 443. (Let's Encrypt is configured) and should forward to the Nginx proxy.

However when I try and hit `https://elasticsearch.homenetwork.local` I get an error in the Traefik logs:

```
time="2017-12-02T22:50:37Z" level=warning msg="Error forwarding to http://10.0.10.3:19200, err: dial tcp 10.0.10.3:19200: getsockopt: no route to host"
```

Given that the Traefik service is on the `10.0.10.0/24` network I do not understand why I get this error. I am using Portainer to track the services and I can see that the Traefik service has an IP address of `10.0.10.4`.

If I run an interactive session to the Nginx Proxy, which has an IP address of `10.0.10.7`, I am able to ping `10.0.10.4` without issue.

The containers are all running Ubuntu. There is no `iptables` involved.

Has anyone seen something like this before? I am struggling to work out what is wrong here so if anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful for them. What is really annoying is that this used to work. I do not recall changing anything but obviously something has.

ElasticSearch service command:

```
docker service create --name elasticsearch \
                      --network elastic_cluster \
                      --constraint "node.labels.app_role == "elasticsearch" \
                      --mode global \
                      --endpoint-mode dnsrr \
                      docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.2 \
                      elasticsearch
```

ElasticSearch Proxy service command:

```
docker service create --name elasticsearch_proxy \
                      --network elastic_cluster \
                      --label traefik.enable=true \
                      --label traefik.backend=elasticsearch_proxy \
                      --label traefik.port=19200 \
                      --label traefik.frontend.rule=Host:elasticsearch.home.turtlesystems.co.uk \
                      --label traefik.docker.network=elastic_cluster \
                      nginx:1.13
```

`nginx.conf` - https://pastebin.com/Q5sXw6aw

Traefik service command

```
docker service create --name reverse_proxy \
                      --network elastic_cluster \
                      --network traefik-net \
                      --constraint "node.role == manager" \
                      --publish 80:80 \
                      --publish 8080:8080 \
                      --publish 443:443 \
                      traefik
```

`traefik.toml` - https://pastebin.com/GFPu8MYJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all of this it turned out that the reason I was having network problems was because of a faulty network cable.

After replacing it everythig worked ok. Thank you for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to mention labels set on your services

```
docker service create --name elasticsearch_proxy \
                      --label traefik.docker.network=elastic_cluster
                      --label traefik.enable=true
                      --label traefik.port=19200
                      --network elastic_cluster \
                      nginx:1.13
```

Comment: You are correct, I did forget them. I have updated my question with the labels I set. Thank you.

Comment: You nginx service does not expose port 19200. You should add `--expose 19200` on you command `docker service create --name elasticsearch_proxy \
                      --network elastic_cluster \
                      --label traefik.enable=true \
                      --label traefik.backend=elasticsearch_proxy \
                      --label traefik.port=19200 \
                      --label traefik.frontend.rule=Host:elasticsearch.home.turtlesystems.co.uk \
                      --label traefik.docker.network=elastic_cluster \
                      nginx:1.13`

Comment: I am confused about this. As Traefik is on the same network as the NGinx service then I should not need to expose the port. In fact that was one of the things I wanted to do so that I did not have loads of exposed ports in my Swarm. Am I missing something? My understanding of exposing a port is so that it is possible to hit the service directly - I am trying to use Traefik to proxy to it here.

Comment: In docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment `Expose ports without publishing them to the host machine - they’ll only be accessible to linked services. Only the internal port can be specified.`

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. However there is no `--expose` option on the `docker service create` command. Is there something that has to be done using the `--publish` option?